# PHP: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php

Can't use function return value in write context.

All the search result responses say its something to do with the empty function, but I'm not using that?

```
foreach ($permission as explode(',', $permissionString)) { // line 44
    if ($this->hasPermission($permission))
        $count++;
}
```

Comment: Your variables in the foreach-statement is in the wrong order. It should be: `foreach (explode(',', $permissionString) as $permission)`. [As stated in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):  `foreach (array_expression as $value)`.

Answer (score 2):

In a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) the expression on the left of the `as` should be the array that you want to iterate through, and the expression on the right is a variable that gets overwritten with the value of each element inside the array.

The reason that you get an error is because php is trying to write an element of `$permission` into `explode(',', $permissionString)`, but this returns an error because `explode(',', $permissionString)` is a function call, not a variable, and only variables can be written to.

To fix this, try reversing the order of the `as`, like this:

```
foreach (explode(',', $permissionString) as $permission) {
```